# How do I capture a noiseprint in Vegas Pro with the Noise Reduction plugin?

Tags: vegas-pro, plugins, noise-reduction, noise

When I go to capture a noiseprint, I don't get a noiseprint or the noiseprint appears around -120 dB as a flat line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add **Event FX** (not Track FX) plugin Noise Reduction by clicking on the "fx" symbol and selecting Noise Reduction.
2. Select a region of noise in the audio.
3. Select "Capture noiseprint" in the effects window.
4. Press play in the Preview window.
5. Optionally, save the captured noiseprint as a preset.